# String gets truncated when inserted in database in c#?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

I am new to .net (Visual Studio .net 2010) trying to insert a string in database SQL Server 2005 with column datatype `varchar(max)`, it truncates the string I insert.

I have tested insertion in query builder and string was not truncated there. Kindly help code pasted below

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath(ResID_int));

FileInfo[] file = dir.GetFiles();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

//   int i = 0;
foreach (FileInfo file2 in file)
{
   name = "/Albums/" + id+ "/"+ file2.Name;
   Response.Write(name);
   DataSet2TableAdapters.Picture1TableAdapter insert = new Picture1TableAdapter();
   insert.InsertData(name, id);
}
```

Comment: check the string size and database column size........

Comment: Can you show us the `Picture1TableAdapter`?? Does it limit the max length of the parameters for `InsertData()` somehow??

Comment: You mean query in adapter? isert query is INSERT INTO [dbo].[Picture1] ([PictureLink], [RestaurantID]) VALUES (@PictureLink, @RestaurantID)

Comment: it worked fine when i tested it through query builder in .net and inserted full string in database

Comment: One of the strings length i am trying to insert is only 87 in length still it gets truncated